# What is the best way to avoid unexpected behavior due to the binary storage of floating point numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, binary

I was writing a simple for loop recently and got some unexpected behavior:

```
for(double x = 0.0; x <= 1.0; x += 0.05)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}
```

This is the output:

```
0
0.05
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6
0.65
0.7
0.75
0.8
0.85
0.9
0.95
```

Notice that 1 doesn't appear even though the condition for continuing the for loop seems to include it. I realize that the reason for this is because decimal numbers are being stored in memory as binary, *i.e.* 1 is not really exactly 1 but actually 1.0000000000000002 (according to the variable watch in Visual Studio). So my question is, what is the best way to avoid this unexpected behavior? One way would be to use the `decimal` type instead of `double`, but most of the `System.Math` functions work on `double`s only, and casting between the two isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always manage yourself the rounding, don't let the system handle it

```
  for(double x = 0.0; Math.Round(x,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) <= 1.0; x += 0.05)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
  }
```

will output

> 0
>   0.05
>   0.1
>   0.15
>   0.2
>   0.25
>   0.3
>   0.35
>   0.4
>   0.45
>   0.5
>   0.55
>   0.6
>   0.65
>   0.7
>   0.75
>   0.8
>   0.85
>   0.9
>   0.95
>   1

Comment: This answer seems best to me, although none are ideal. I don't like the idea of iterating over something different just to avoid floating-point errors. I wish there was a way to tell the compiler to "round sanely", e.g. it is probably safe to assume 1.0000000000000002 is really 1 but in lieu of that I think a manual Math.Round() is the way to go.

Comment: in lieu of what exactly?  You have to consider significant digits when doing any math with decimals.

Answer (score 9):

Don't test doubles for equality.

Here you could use integer arithmetic instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; ++i)
{
    double x = (double)i / 20.0;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

In other cases it might be more appropriate to test if the difference between two doubles is sufficiently small rather than using an equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This is referred to as floating-point error and a lot has been written about it. One solution for your case would be to define an error, such as

```
err = .000001
```

and do the comparison to within err of 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

can you not scale up and use int

```
 for(int ix=0; ix < 1000; ix += 50)
 {

  }
```

then divide by 1000 if you need to. but this way you get precise loop behaviour